# steady state of a continuous-time birth-death process

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains

we consider a continuous-time  birth-death process $\{X(t),t\geq 0\}$ with discrete state space taking non0negative integer values $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$. The transition rates of the process $\{X(t)\}$ are given by

for $m>0$,
$q_{m,m+1}=\lambda$, $q_{m,\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor}=\mu$, $q_{m,m}=-\lambda-\mu$.

for $m=0$, 
$q_{m,m+1}=\lambda$, $q_{m,m}=-\lambda$.

The death part is different from the conventional one in birth-death process. At state $X(t)=m$, it may jump to $m+1$ or $\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor$ or stay in $m$.

Is it possible to obtain the steady state distribution from the steady state ODE?